# Heroku deployment failiure

Tags: node.js, angularjs, typescript, heroku, web-applications

i tried to push my angular app to heroku, followed some steps on internet that told me to change the package.json and make a server.js. But in the end i got the message saying "Not found"
when i tried to see the webpage through the link https://silenxika.herokuapp.com/ thus seeking for help now

Below is the build log

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  16.13.2
       engines.npm (package.json):   8.1.2
       
       Resolving node version 16.13.2...
       Downloading and installing node 16.13.2...
       npm 8.1.2 already installed with node
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       added 1016 packages, and audited 1017 packages in 28s
       
       91 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       41 vulnerabilities (3 low, 38 moderate)
       
       To address all issues, run:
         npm audit fix
       
       Run `npm audit` for details.
       
-----> Build
       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > silenxika@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild
       > ng build --prod
       
Option "--prod" is deprecated: No need to use this option as this builder defaults to configuration "production".
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
- Copying assets...
✔ Copying assets complete.
- Generating index html...
✔ Index html generation complete.
       
       Initial Chunk Files           | Names         |  Raw Size | Estimated Transfer Size
./src/styles.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[4].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[4].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[2]!./src/styles.css - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning
(8:1) postcss-import: @import must precede all other statements (besides @charset)
Warning: /tmp/build_fe342bb2/src/app/main/navbar/navbar.component.css exceeded maximum budget. Budget 2.00 kB was not met by 381 bytes with a total of 2.37 kB.
Warning: /tmp/build_fe342bb2/src/app/pr/productblocks/productblocks.component.css exceeded maximum budget. Budget 2.00 kB was not met by 468 bytes with a total of 2.46 kB.
Warning: /tmp/build_fe342bb2/src/app/pr/productdiscordbot/productdiscordbot.component.css exceeded maximum budget. Budget 2.00 kB was not met by 478 bytes with a total of 2.47 kB.
Warning: /tmp/build_fe342bb2/src/app/pr/productpython/productpython.component.css exceeded maximum budget. Budget 2.00 kB was not met by 490 bytes with a total of 2.48 kB.
Warning: /tmp/build_fe342bb2/src/app/pr/productwebapps/productwebapps.component.css exceeded maximum budget. Budget 2.00 kB was not met by 477 bytes with a total of 2.47 kB.
       main.5712c2806cc4359c.js      | main          | 215.14 kB |                53.95 kB
       polyfills.25274fd5295a26dd.js | polyfills     |  36.22 kB |                11.51 kB
       runtime.65e870f2d783c48d.js   | runtime       |   1.05 kB |               602 bytes
       styles.9a90c74daf5db7df.css   | styles        | 550 bytes |               227 bytes
       
       | Initial Total | 252.94 kB |                66.27 kB
       
       Build at: 2022-01-24T08:56:09.827Z - Hash: c130164e2fe9624a - Time: 20079ms
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       
       removed 1 package, and audited 74 packages in 4s
       
       2 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 49.6M
-----> Launching...
       Released v5
       https://silenxika.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: When it is a heroku problem, a different error page is displayed, so it must be a problem of your application, not of the deployment.

Comment: i mean shouldn't that problem mirror in my terminal while i ng serve my app in localhost?

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the route to which you access the application, try to enter a more specific route to see if something appears.

Comment: yea i think i got it, i messed up with the server.js file

Comment: Okay, edit or do another question if u cant solve the problem.

Comment: That's your _deploy_ log, and it shows a successful deployment. For runtime errors you need to look in your runtime logs, e.g. by running `heroku logs`.